# Filtering a JSON with Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to filter a JSON using filter and I'm not getting the clubProducts to return as I hoped (allProducts works fine).  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you

```
const state = {
  added: [],
  all: [
    {
      id: 'bcd755a6-9a19-94e1-0a5d-426c0303454f',
      name: 'Iced Coffee',
      description: 'Coffee, now featuring ice.',
      image: 'https://images.com',
      price: 899,
      fxCategory: 'Coffee'
    },
    {
      id: 'cc919e21-9a19-94e1-ace9-426c0303454f',
      name: 'The 2ndItem',
      description: 'Wouldn't you like to know.',
      image: 'https://images.com',
      price: 499,
      fxCategory: 'Club'
    }
  ]
}

const getters = {
    allProducts: state => state.all,
    clubProducts: state => function () {
        return state.all.filter(item => item.fxCategory == 'Club')
    }
}
```

EDIT: Updated with latest attempt as per suggestions

Comment: You forgot to quote `'Club'` in your comparison. And it should be `state.all.filter()`. And there's no need to wrap that `filter()` expression in a function.

Comment: It's a pain to filter a string, maybe filtering an object would help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Comment: As it was noted, `state => function () {` is likely a mistake. Since you didn't provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that shows how the function is used, this is guesswork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made two mistakes: you can use `filter()` only on an array (ie `state.all` in your case), and in your comparison you didn't quote the string 'Club'.

Also, your `filter()` can be written in a shorter way, as such:

```
clubProducts: state.all.filter(item => item.fxCategory == 'Club')
```

See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for more.

Comment: Thanks Reyedy.  I tried with your suggestions and I'm still not getting anything returned.  But using allProducts, I get the expected response.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Reyedy you can call filter function directly in 'clubProducts' field and this example is works.

But you may get an error because you use single quotes in 'description' field.

Try in state.all

```
description: "Wouldn't you like to know.",
```

instead of

```
description: 'Wouldn't you like to know.',
```

This is the only place I got an error trying to repeat your example.